# Store & access database on remote server

Tags: android, mysql, database

I uploaded my sql database to remote server(eu5.org). I am using PHP script to access that database. To establish a connection there is this command..

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
```

Now i dont know what to specify in these fields..

```
host: localhost or 127.0.0.1 or eu5.org (while logging in there is a field FTP Server: eu5.org).

username: vipul.eu5.org(my domain at this site) or root(username for localhost) or 666666(a 6 digit numeric username for accessing phpmyadmin of eu5.org)

password: my password at eu5.org or password of local mysql database (phpmyadmin).
```

Moreover after this , there is this command

```
mysql_select_db("database name", $con);
```

at my localhost my database name was "main". after importing it to phpmyadmin of eu5.org.. my tables of this database are listed under the database name "666666"(6 digit auto generated username for phpmyadmin  )

I am a beginner...any help would be appreciated..

I was able to run my phpscript and access my database at localhost

Comment: host should be the "localhost"

Comment: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'username i entered'@'hostname i provided' (using password: YES)

Comment: you need to pass the credentials if you have not set any pass 
in place of username "root" and for password just ""

Answer (score 0):

You have no permission set. Code is ok and you pass username, pass and host, that's enough. Maybe you are using wrong username or password.

Comment: So which of above mentioned username, password and database name i should use????

Comment: Trying out will help? :) I'd try the credentials you also use when logging in to phpMyAdmin. Of course the remote server and not your local machine. That's ... well... local. :)